# Why make learning programming difficult for someone who wants to learn?

Tags: discussion, questions

Several months ago I got banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow in order to improve my programming in Python. I was only asking like 2 questions a week, and I was putting a lot of effort into it. I feel that punishing people who are only trying to have fun and learn defeats the purpose of programming. I feel like the only reason I got banned was because the questions weren't researched in the perfect manner that a Stack Overflow user thinks they *should* be asked, which methods aren't as obvious the people running the site think it should be.

Before I got banned, I learned some C and asked questions on how to make a text based program do what I want, and ended up being a real fun program to make.

But instead of going back and changing questions that were perfectly reasonable to ask at the time, I've since wised up and started learning Microsoft Basic out of a book designed for absolute beginners and stop going online to ask anyone questions because you all have defeated the purpose of having an open forum. Maybe you should start charging money to reinforce the career mentality of the site, and prevent stupid n00bs from getting frustrated?

Comment: I repeat: We are **not** a forum. We are a **Q&A** site, not a forum for discussion. You ask questions, we give answers. Complaining that SO is not something it never intended to be makes no sense. If you want a forum, SO is not for you.

Comment: *"you all have defeated the purpose of having an open forum"* Looks like they did the right thing. This is not a forum (like Andrew wrote) and we're not here to teach basics.

Comment: Not only is this not a forum, it's also not a "help" site, but rather a question and answer site. Your problems are stemming from having expectations about this site that are not true, and to fix this, please go through the [help] sub-sections to see just what this site is for and how to best use it.

Comment: Consider reading over [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: By closing the questions and downvoting them, we're trying to teach you that such questions aren't on topic here. If you want to contribute to this site, you must follow the existing guidelines.

Comment: *Before I got banned, I learned some C* well, there's your problem.

Comment: No pain, no gain. SO can generate frustration sometimes. but also satisfaction when you can make the "good" question or answer. It grants quality that made it the best IT support free site. In certain cases, can improve curriculum. Any of these benefits have a price.

Answer (score 35):

> But instead of going back and changing questions that were perfectly
>   reasonable to ask at the time, I've since wised up and started
>   learning Microsoft Basic out of a book designed for absolute beginners
>   and stop going online to ask anyone questions

That is *beautiful* - because it's *exactly* what you were supposed to do.  Congratulations! (I say this with only a little bit of snark.)

Stack Overflow is not there to replace learning resources designed for absolute beginners.

It's something it can't do, doesn't want to do, and was never designed to do.

> Maybe you should start charging money to reinforce the career
>   mentality of the site, and prevent stupid n00bs from getting
>   frustrated?

That's not an unreasonable idea on its own: tutoring and teaching does follow that formula, after all. Teachers deal with the same "newbie" questions every day, and they get paid in return.

It's not something Stack Overflow is likely to ever try, though. The consensus around here is that creating money incentives to answerers would destroy the place. The current model is for programmers to donate slices of their time, for free, on at least somewhat challenging and interesting questions - something a complete newbie is likely to have problems with.

The model's worked tremendously well and is unlikely to ever change here. A paid model would have to find a home elsewhere.

Approaches in that direction certainly exist, although none is as big as SO. There is [Codementor](http://codementor.io), for example, but most of the mentors there charge a pretty hefty hourly rate, so it's normally more for businesses looking to "rent" certain skill sets for a short period of time.

Comment: No no no. You don't incentivize answerers. You take the money and give nothing to your drones.

Answer (score 14):

> I feel that punishing people who are only trying to have fun and learn defeats the purpose of programming.

I know for lots of people the *purpose* of programming isn't to have fun and learn.  Most of the people here are *professionals*.  Programming is our job; our livelihood.  We may enjoy programming; I know I do, but I don't do it *because it's fun*.  It's not the *reason* programming exists.

More importantly though, the "purpose of programming" isn't relevant to *the purpose of the site*.  The purpose of *the site* isn't to have fun or to help you learn how to program.  The purpose of the site is to create a repository of knowledge for the larger programming community based on quality questions with quality useful answers.  Your contributions clearly weren't contributing to that goal, even if you were having fun posting them.

> I feel like the only reason i got banned was because the questions weren't researched in the perfect manner that a stack overflow programmer thinks they should be asked,

If your questions weren't well researched, that's certainly an appropriate response, yes.  Your questions likely also had other problems as well, for example, you have a question that's closed as "unclear" because people couldn't understand it.

> which methods aren't as obvious the people running the forum think it should be.

So you read through the help center, and the frequently asked questions, you got feedback on the posts that you made, informing you that your posts were problematic and why, and then *you still continued providing problematic content anyway*.  This seems to be rather clearly a case of you *knowing* that you were posting problematic content, but *not caring* rather than it not being clear to you that you were performing problematic actions (especially after the first few).

> But instead of going back and changing questions that were perfectly reasonable to ask at the time, I've since wised up and started learning microsoft basic out of a book designed for absolute beginners and stop going online to ask anyone questions because you all have defeated the purpose of having an open forum.

Given where it seems you're at, that's almost certainly what you *should* be doing.  SO isn't designed to take the place of an intro programming book, and doesn't try to.  Use the right tool for the right job; if you want to learn the basics of programming, a book like that *is the right tool*.

> Maybe you should start charging money to reinforce the career mentality of the forums, and prevent stupid n00bs from getting frustrated?

I'm not sure that'd actually accomplish that goal.  It'd result in less questions being asked period, but I don't see it as discouraging bad questions more than good questions.  If anything it would *encourage* the behavior that someone asking a question deserves help from others, that the question is only there for them; this is essentially asking for private tutoring or hiring a consultant, and that's simply not the job SO is attempting to solve.  One of the main reasons the site's founders created the site was that one of the main sites in the field of programming Q/A *did* use this paywall model, and that angered the site's founders greatly.

Comment: I overall like the website, and I sympathize with both answers. However, when I Google programming questions often questions from this website pop up, so it bothers me that my approach is disliked by the people who could help me...I just accept that the world of programmers is by necessity a lonely one

Comment: @thinksinbinary The fact that the site has lots of high quality and generally useful content that you regularly come across is a direct result of the way that the site works, and it's exactly why it *doesn't* want you to ask your low quality questions that aren't going to be useful to anyone else.

Comment: @thinksinbinary: meaning you haven't understood a word that anyone has posted in response to your question.

Comment: I think you haven't understood a word of my frustrations hovercraft, which is pretty sad considering that it was all clearly stated

Comment: *"when I Google programming questions often questions from this website pop up"* - that's what is supposed to happen, why don't you see that as a sign of success? "*the world of programmers is by necessity a lonely one"* - that is not at all true.

Comment: @thinksinbinary I think we understand your frustrations pretty well, but maybe some of them stem from you thinking Stack Overflow is something it isn't. It's not the only place on the Internet to ask questions at, and I'm sure there are more empowering & mentor-y ones. They are worth finding and checking out. That SO is (mostly) all business doesn't mean its users are lonely - just *busy.*

Comment: @thinksinbinary We *do* understand your frustrations.  And we understand that they stem from thinking that SO is something that it isn't, and *doesn't want to be*.  This has been explained to you.  You know that SO doesn't want the content you're trying to provide, no matter how much you want to provide it, and you know *why* SO doesn't want that content.

Comment: That comment was not directed at anyone but hovercraft of eels, for him to think I don't understand what you all are saying is really obtuse. But thanks to everyone for being helpful