# A tag relative to programming/IT learning

Tags: discussion, tags, education

I've asked a question some time ago about the usefulness of an example in w3schools. I think this kind of question can fit perfectly with a tag about "learn programming" or similar... because it was about the best/more effective examples to use to make beginners understand key concepts... but I haven't found one yet regarding the subject. It exists? If no, can be useful to create it?

I'm not asking to create a tag for SO tutorials, newbies etc, but a tag relative to the "science" of teaching programming with the most suitable examples/explanations. My (upvoted) question in SO was about a w3schools code example that I've found useless, to clarify my doubt about it and to find something better to explain utilization of a specific concept (closures).

Comment: There are already lots and lots and lots of web sites that offer tutorials and examples.  There was an attempt to add something similar to SO, it was a giant failure.  SO just doesn't have to do *everything*.

Comment: I don't want SO to became a tutorial, but I'm searching a tag relative to learning/teaching programming and the more effective examples to do it.

Comment: @Lore SO is a site for programming questions, not for questions about education or teaching techniques.

Comment: I'm not even sure if "teaching programming" would be on-topic for SO.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the site's guidelines, but if you want to ask questions about teaching programming specifically, then maybe [cs educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/) is the place ask?

Comment: I honestly wasn't aware of this community. I think my question can be moved here.

Comment: Meta effect inbound. Better flag and ask a mod to migrate. I think they might very well do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why make learning programming difficult for someone who wants to learn?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345469/why-make-learning-programming-difficult-for-someone-who-wants-to-learn)

Comment: @Will: done. Meanwhile my rep is going down every minute because of the link XD

Comment: There is [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/) for questions about teaching computer science. Check there to see if your questions on this subject are on-topic or not.

Comment: @gnat What does that have to do with this question.  How do the answers there answer this question?  Just because both questions have the word "learning" in their title doesn't make them duplicates.

Comment: @Servy well possibly prior duplicate target that you [singlehandedly reopened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/363686/revisions) was a better fit: [Benefit of creating a newbie or beginner tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261526/839601)

Comment: @gnat But this isn't asking to create a tag for questions asked by a new programmer, it's asking for a tag about *teaching techniques*, which is entirely different.  A tag for questions asking about teaching techniques isn't a meta tag, unlike a tag indicating the difficulty of the question, it's simply a topic that's off topic for SO.

Answer (score 9):

The question is off topic on SO.  SO is a site for programming questions, not for education questions, so naturally since the question is off topic there shouldn't be a tag for such questions.  Also note that your question is primarily opinion based.  It just doesn't have an objective answer at all, it is a request for people's opinions.

Comment: In some circumstance I think it can fit: my question was not opinion based, but I asked to explain me a specific fact that seemed to vanish the utility of example. In my opinion a learning tag can exist in SO... it's only an opinion, obviously.

Comment: @Lore "What do you think about this?" Is *specifically* asking for opinions.  It's not something that is asking for facts.  There is no objective answer to that question.  Same same with, "Do you have some other example less problematic (and more useful) for the beginners?"  That's asking for *opinions*, and there is no objective measurement by which you can determine if an answer is "correct" or not.  Finally asking, "Why should I [...]" is *also* asking for opinions.  Why someone might or might not want to do something is *an opinion*, not something with an objectively correct answer.

Comment: The objective fact is using of a closure that practically doesn't solves a problem but only "translate" it to another point. The specific question was "have this kind of example a purpose that I don't see, or is a nonsense example?". Who read the question upvoted and answered, also experienced users of SO.

Comment: @Lore Lots of people love sharing their opinions.  It's *fun* to argue over what color to paint the bikeshed.  As a result, questions asking for people's opinions often get upvoted, particularly by newer users.  That doesn't mean the question isn't opinion based.  There are questions that you could ask about that snippet that wouldn't be asking for opinions; there are things that you could ask about how that program behaves that would have answers that could be objectively determined to be correct or false, but you didn't ask such a question, you asked for people's *opinions* on it.